# Explicit Cast of XmlRpcValue to double

Tags: c++, casting, xml-rpc, explicit-conversion

I am trying to cast a XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue to a double value. The implicit casting method did not work so I will have to explicitly cast it. However, I cannot get any of the 3 explicit casting types to work.

The XmlRpcValue is a vector of vector of doubles. In the .yaml file, the field looks like:

```
DOF: [[0, 3.5], [0, 3.5], [-3.14159, 3.14159]]
```

Now I want to read each value into a double. I have tried the following:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<dof.size();i++) {
    double min = static_cast<double>(dof[i][0]);
    double max = static_cast<double>(dof[i][1]);
    //Do stuff
```

with static_cast, reinterpret_cast, and dynamic_cast. I don't feel like I completely understand everything with explicit caste, but I think static_cast is what I need. I tried dynamic and reinterpret just to see what would happen. They all failed with the following messages:

> static - invalid static_cast from type ‘const XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue’ to
>   type ‘double’
>
> reinterpret - error: invalid cast from type ‘const
>   XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue’ to type ‘double’
>
> dynamic - cannot dynamic_cast ‘(&
>   dof.XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::operator)->XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::operator’
>   (of type ‘const class XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue’) to type ‘double’ (target
>   is not pointer or reference)

If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:

I tried to static_cast to a std::vector< std::vector >. It failed to compile with:

```
~/my_path/main.cpp: In function ‘void setDOF(XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue)’:
~/my_path/main.cpp:64:97: error: conversion from ‘const XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue’ to ‘std::vector<std::vector<double> >::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ is ambiguous
~/my_path/main.cpp:58:6: note: candidates are:
In file included from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/node_handle.h:51:0,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/sterlingm/ros_workspace/src/ramp/ramp_planner/src/main.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:92:5: note: XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::operator double&() <near match>
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:92:5: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’ to ‘XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:91:5: note: XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::operator int&() <near match>
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:91:5: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’ to ‘XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:90:5: note: XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::operator bool&() <near match>
/opt/ros/hydro/include/XmlRpcValue.h:90:5: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’ to ‘XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue*’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/vector:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/format.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/sterlingm/ros_workspace/src/ramp/ramp_planner/src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:292:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = std::vector<double>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::vector<double>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::vector<double> >]’
make[2]: *** [ramp/ramp_planner/CMakeFiles/ramp_planner.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: From the errors it seems that dof contains vectors of XmlRpcValues. Are you sure that the vectors contain doubles?

Comment: That's right - dof is a vector of vectors of XmlRpcValues. So dof[i] is a vector of XmlRpcValues and dof[i][j] is a single XmlRpcValue. I want to go through each vector (dof[i]) and convert the 1st and 2nd elements to doubles.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The two types are completely unrelated.

Comment: Hmm, I was mistaken then. dof is just a single XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue whose value is set to a vector of vectors of doubles (the value is shown in the question). I have tried to static_cast dof to a std::vector< std::vector<double> >, but I still get an error. I edited the question with the error.

Comment: The thing is, casts don't work like this. You can't simply cast something to an unrelated type. You may want to read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845695/static-cast-what-does-conversion-between-compatible-types-mean

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this thread is over two years old, but it was the first result on google when I hit this issue. While it is not shown in the section of code above the dof variable was probably declared const.

The issue is that the method that allows you to treat an XmlRpcValue as a double is not a const method and so cannot be used with a const XmlRpcValue.

This means that if you wish to retrieve the value of a double stored in a const XmlRpcValue you have three options.

1. rewrite your code to remove the const
2. copy the const XmlValue to a temporary non-const XmlValue and then retreive the double
3. cast away the const

Comment: Thank you! Getting a double out of an XmlRpcValue took me way longer than it should have.